# Jest tests for coffee.ERB files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, jestjs, erb

In a Rails project I've got some JavaScript files that contain ERB syntax, i.e.

```
// en_store.coffee.erb

EnStore =
  activities:
    title: 'Delete Note?'
    image: '<%= asset_path("crm/sections/en/calendar.png") %>'

module.exports.EnStore = EnStore
```

And the test:

```
// en_store.test.coffee

import { EnStore } from 'stores/en_store'

describe 'EN Store', () ->

  // This test passes.
  it 'should provide hard typed translation', () ->
    expect(EnStore.activities.title).toBe('Delete Note?')

  // This one fails as the EnStore.activities.image contains '<%= asset_path("crm/sections/en/calendar.png") %>' as a string and not the actual interpolated value.
  it 'should provide asset path', () ->
    expect(EnStore.activities.image).toBe('[This is not interpolated]')
```

Attempt to test it with Jest results in an error, as the ERB part is not getting interpolated. Outside of test this is handled by Webpack, through the `rails-erb-loader`. How can I make it work with Jest? Is there any existing `transform` package that would let me do this?

Or is there alternative to Jest that would let me test those type of files?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no babel support or plugin for `.erb` files you need there is no easy way of transforming your source files into something `jest` can consume.

There a few viable options, though.

#### 1) Consume webpack loaders as Babel plugins

[`babel-plugin-webpack-loaders`](https://github.com/istarkov/babel-plugin-webpack-loaders) is a Babel plugin meant to use **webpack loaders to transform your files** via babel.

This is the solution mentioned by [jest's docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack#configuring-jest-to-find-our-files) for projects based on non-trivial Webpack configurations, but the project is **no more maintained** and officially compatible only with **webpack v1**.

#### 2) Write a Jests custom transformer

Jest doesn't provide webpack integration out of the box, but provides source codes transformation via [transformers](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#transform-object-string-string).

You might consider [writing a custom `.erb` transformer](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react#custom-transformers) based on [Webpack's Rails erb loader](https://github.com/usabilityhub/rails-erb-loader).

#### 3) Integrate Jest and Webpack with third party utility

Even if not officially supported by Jest's team  [`jest-webpack`](https://github.com/mzgoddard/jest-webpack) is a project meant to integrate **Jest** with your existing **Webpack configuration**.